# Unable to autowire the service inside my authentication filter in Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to authenticate user by token, But when i try to auto wire one my services inside the `AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter` i get null pointer exception. **because autowired service is null** , how can i fix this issue ?

My `AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter` class

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.marketplace"})
public class AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myServices")
    private MyServices service;

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, String[]> parms = request.getParameterMap();

        if (parms.containsKey("token")) {
            try {
                String strToken = parms.get("token")[0]; // grab the first "token" parameter

                User user = service.getUserByToken(strToken);
                System.out.println("Token: " + strToken);

                DateTime dt = new DateTime();
                DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                DateTime createdDate = fmt.parseDateTime(strToken);
                Minutes mins = Minutes.minutesBetween(createdDate, dt);


                if (user != null && mins.getMinutes() <= 30) {
                    System.out.println("valid token found");

                    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
                    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));

                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getEmailId(), user.getPassword());
                    token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails((HttpServletRequest) request));
                    Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getEmailId(), user.getPassword(), authorities); //this.authenticationProvider.authenticate(token);

                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                }else{
                    System.out.println("invalid token");
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("no token found");
        }
        // continue thru the filter chain
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

I Tried adding follwing in my `AppConfig`

```
@Bean(name="myServices")
    public MyServices stockService() {
        return new MyServiceImpl();
    }
```

My AppConfig Annotations are

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.marketplace")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
```

Comment: is your Bean ```MyServices``` created when you look at the logs? You could try adding ```@Component``` at your ```MyServices```

Comment: Yeah i tried adding @ComponentScan and Service was created!

Comment: Does your AppConfig class have `@Configuration` annotation?

Comment: Along with ```@ComponentScan``` you need to add ```@Component``` to ```AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter```

Comment: @RahulYadav i just updated my question with annotations i have added!

Comment: @AmmSokun No luck with that :(

Comment: It feels like the beans are defined in different contexts. What Spring version are you using? If you use a web.xml how does that look?

Comment: No @CristianSevescu it is in same context i just fixed it will post answer now!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I just made it work by adding

**SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);**

I am unsure why we should do this even when i tried adding explicit qualifier. and now the code looks like

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, String[]> parms = request.getParameterMap();

        if (parms.containsKey("token")) {
```

Comment: You may want to consider adding it to @PostConstruct method to prevent it from being executed in each doFilter() call.

Comment: You can put this in the init method of the filter call

Comment: Current WebApplicationContext is not available for processing of Filter: Make sure this class gets constructed in a Spring web application after the Spring WebApplicationContext has been initialized. Proceeding without injection.

Answer (score 68):

You cannot use dependency injection from a filter out of the box. Although you are using GenericFilterBean your Servlet Filter is not managed by spring. As noted by the javadocs

> This generic filter base class has no dependency on the Spring
>   org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext concept. Filters
>   usually don't load their own context but rather access service beans
>   from the Spring root application context, accessible via the filter's
>   ServletContext (see
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils).

In plain English we cannot expect spring to inject the service, but we can lazy set it on the first call.
E.g.

```
public class AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    private MyServices service;
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if(service==null){
            ServletContext servletContext = request.getServletContext();
            WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
            service = webApplicationContext.getBean(MyServices.class);
        }
        your code ...    
    }

}
```

Comment: @haim Why do I get `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'mypackage.TokenAuthenticationService' available` when using this solution?

Comment: Sounds like a problem in the TokenAuthenticationService defintion. Should be annotaied with Bean in config or used in XML or Service in with componet scan etc

Answer (score 31):

It's an old enough question, but I'll add my answer for those who like me google this issue.

You must inherit your filter from `GenericFilterBean` and mark it as a Spring `@Component`

```
@Component
public class MyFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Autowired
    private MyComponent myComponent;

 //implementation

}
```

And then register it in Spring context:

```
@Configuration
public class MyFilterConfigurerAdapter extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MyFilter myFilter;

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean myFilterRegistrationBean() {
        FilterRegistrationBean regBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        regBean.setFilter(myFilter);
        regBean.setOrder(1);
        regBean.addUrlPatterns("/myFilteredURLPattern");

        return regBean;
    }
}
```

This properly autowires your components in the filter.

Comment: You just nailed it. Thanks

Comment: This example is applicable only for Spring boot as `FilterRegistrationBean` exists only there

Comment: not working for me. Also WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  is now deprecated

Answer (score 7):

If your filter class extends GenericFilterBean you can get a reference to a bean in your app context this way:

```
public void initFilterBean() throws ServletException {

@Override
public void initFilterBean() throws ServletException {

        WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext =
            WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
        //reference to bean from app context
        yourBeanToInject = webApplicationContext.getBean(yourBeanToInject.class);

        //do something with your bean
        propertyValue = yourBeanToInject.getValue("propertyName");
}
```

And here is less explicit way for those who doesn't like hardcoding bean names or need to inject more than one bean reference into the filter:

```
@Autowired
private YourBeanToInject yourBeanToInject;

@Override
public void initFilterBean() throws ServletException{

    SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(this, getServletContext());

    //do something with your bean
    propertyValue = yourBeanToInject.getValue("propertyName");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your bean filter and pass as a parameter whatever you need. I know out of Spring context where the filter it is, you cannot get the dependency injection that the auto-scan of spring does. But not 100% sure if there´s a fancy annotation that you can put in your filter to do some magic stuff

```
   <filter>
   <filter-name>YourFilter</filter-name>
       <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>YourFilter</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

and then inject bean in the spring.xml

```
  <bean id="YourFilter" class="com.YourFilter">
     <property name="param">
        <value>values</value>
     </property>
  </bean>
```

Comment: Can you help me with Java Config for this i am not good with xml config!!

Comment: The first xml it´s on your web.xml(servlet conf) and the second must be your applicationContext.xml(Spring conf). You have plenty of tutorials that explain how to configure your framework

Answer (score 1):

I am late to the party but this solution worked for me.

Add a ContextLoaderListener in web.xml. applicationContext can have dependency beans.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Then add in MyFilter SpringBeanAutowiringSupport processInjectionBasedOnServletContext which will add the webapplicationcontext into the filter which will add all the dependencies.

```
@Component
public class MyFilter implements Filter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userSessionServiceImpl")
    private UserSessionService userSessionServiceImpl;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain 
    chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        if (userSessionServiceImpl == null) {
            ServletContext context = httpRequest.getSession().getServletContext();
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(this, context);
    }

       .... (for brevity)
    }
```

}