# Spring Security define a custom anonymous filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

We are using Spring Security version 4. By default the anonymous user has the `ROLE_ANONYMOUS` assigned.

We want to add more roles for the anonymous user.

I tried to extend the `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` and add it to Spring Security context as below:

```xml
<http entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">
    <custom-filter ref="sabaAnonymousAuthenticationFilter" position="ANONYMOUS_FILTER"/> 
    <anonymous enabled="false"/>
.....

<beans:bean id="sabaAnonymousAuthenticationFilter"
                class="foo.bar.CustomAnonymousAuthenticationFilter">
                <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="SomeUniqueKeyForThisApplication"/>
</beans:bean>
```

And the class:

```java
public class CustomAnonymousAuthenticationFilter extends AnonymousAuthenticationFilter {
    @Inject 
    HelperClass aHelperClass;

    public CustomAnonymousAuthenticationFilter(String key) {
        super(key);
        getAuthorities().add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_FOO_BAR")); 
        ......
    }
}
```

The above code change anonymous roles and add `ROLE_FOO_BAR`, but I can not `@Inject` or `@Autowire` other Spring beans in this filter.

Please let me know:

1. Is this a correct way of defining a custom anonymous filter?
2. How can I `authowire` other beans here?

I used same approach for defining a custom `UserDetailsService` and the `autowire` works there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand the [spring security documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#anonymous-config) one could add an additional role to the user like this:

```
<bean id="anonymousAuthFilter"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="key" value="foobar"/>
    <property name="userAttribute" value="anonymousUser,ROLE_ANONYMOUS, ROLE_FOOBAR"/>
</bean>
```

This way you could probably avoid writing your own Authentication Filter.

Try it out. I hope it suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to have my own class, as the `roles` can not be hard coded in xml and should read from a file.

Comment: Perhaps this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32494398/unable-to-autowire-the-service-inside-my-authentication-filter-in-spring will resolve your autowire problem.