# How to save all APIs in Spring Boot application to database?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, netflix-zuul

I have to save all API request along with response to database in Spring Boot application.

I should save following:

```
request URL
request parameters
request body
response body
```

How can I do it generically so that I don't need to write code in every method ?
Please suggest how to do that

Comment: Using an Interceptor? https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor

Comment: Spring provides actuators it may be helpful or you can [refer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744875/spring-boot-how-to-log-all-requests-and-responses-with-exceptions-in-single-pl)

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be plenty of examples on how to log those using filters, so you can inject a repository into one and have it save instead of logging.

Edit - sorry, failed to include `chain.doFilter(request, response);`

```
  //Filter
    @Component
    public class RequestResponseLoggingFilter implements Filter {

        private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

        //Inject repo here

        @Override
        public void doFilter(
          ServletRequest request, 
          ServletResponse response, 
          FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

            HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

            //Read data from req and res, save to repo
            LOGGER.info("Logged : " + req.getRequestURI());

            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

        @Override
        public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

        @Override
        public void destroy() {}
    }
```

```
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<RequestResponseLoggingFilter> loggingFilter(){
        FilterRegistrationBean<RequestResponseLoggingFilter> registrationBean 
          = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();

        registrationBean.setFilter(new RequestResponseLoggingFilter());
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/**");

        return registrationBean;    
    }
```

[Unable to autowire the service inside my authentication filter in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32494398/unable-to-autowire-the-service-inside-my-authentication-filter-in-spring) is something you'll probably need.

Comment: the code you provided is not working for me. can you please provide complete code or any blog ?

Comment: Blog with working filter implementation - https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-add-filter/