# Dynamicallly retrieve Spring Boot CORS Configuration from database for specific method in a Controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, cors, microservices, jhipster

I am trying to set the CORS configuration at Controller level using

```
@CrossOrigin on Controller and Handler Method

public class AccountController {

@CrossOrigin("retreive data from DB")
@RequestMapping("/{id}")
public Account retrieve(@PathVariable Long id) {
    // ...
}
```

}

I have tried using below  but its set only when the spring boot starts and takes changes only when the service is restarted next time ...

```
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
   // CorsConfiguration config = jHipsterProperties.getCors();

       CorsConfiguration config=CorsService.fetchCorsConfigFromDb;
    if (config.getAllowedOrigins() != null && !config.getAllowedOrigins().isEmpty()) {
        log.debug("Registering CORS filter");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/api/**", config);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/management/**", config);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/v2/api-docs", config);
    }
    return new CorsFilter(source);
}
```

> `fetchCorsConfigFromDb` will fetch data from DB. Any changes from DB will be reflected only when Spring Boot App is restarted...

Answer (score 5):

To implement this functionality you can use a basic filter in which you can write your custom database logic to add CORS header to your request based on some database attribute value.

You can refer to below example to implement this functionality using spring-data-jpa.

Add DB connection attributes to application.properties file

**application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root
```

Create a entity with below attribute to save URL in DB

**Cors.java**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Cors {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String url;
    private boolean isAllowed;
}
```

And in the repository added a `findByUrl` method to get value from DB based on URL

**CorsRepository.java**

```
public interface CorsRepository extends JpaRepository<Cors,Long> {
    Optional<Cors> findByUrl(String url);
}
```

Below is my filter to intercept request and make DB call and if `isAllowed` is true then i add cors headers to make a successful request

**CorsFilter.java**

```
@Component
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {
    @Autowired
    CorsRepository corsRepository;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException { }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        String url = request.getRequestURI().toString();
        System.out.println(url);

        Optional<Cors> cors = corsRepository.findByUrl(url);
        if(cors.isPresent() && cors.get().isAllowed()){
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me");
        }
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() { }
}
```

You can create a sample controller like this:

**CorsTesterController.java**

```
@RestController
public class CorsTesterController {

    @GetMapping("/api/v1/test")
    String getResponse(){
        return "test response";
    }
}
```

and insert values to DB to allow/disallow a url to test this example code.

```
testdb=# select * from cors;
 id | is_allowed |       url
----+------------+-----------------
  1 | f          | /api/v1/block
  2 | t          | /api/v1/allowed
```

Comment: Great !! Nice idea . if you find the question relevant . please upvote the question                  @Ajit Soman

Comment: Why not autowiring the CorsRepository rather than using getBean() on ApplicationCOntext?

Comment: you can check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32494398/unable-to-autowire-the-service-inside-my-authentication-filter-in-spring

Comment: @GaëlMarziou, You are right . `@Autowiring` will work in Filter with `@Component`. annotation.

Comment: @MohammadJaved. I have updated answer as per comment

Answer (score 1):

**For** `CorsService.fetchCorsConfigFromDb;` 
**it should load from cache**

then you can **update** your cache at **run-time**

you should implement `CorsService.fetchCorsConfig();`

1. this method should look for any cors configuration in cache first ,if there any configurations found load it directly from cache else you will retrive cors from db and update your cache
2. create update cors at runtime method `CorsService.updateCorsConfig();` , this should update your cors in db and then update cache .

Comment: Thanks !!  If you find the question relevant . please upvote the question

Answer (score 0):

Usually reading properties from database - not secured variant and if you lost connection to database you service can startup not correct.

Anyway you can do it, but would like to draw attention to default support by Spring a lot of remote properties sources

For loading custom properties you may use
`spring.config.import=optional:file:./cors.yml`
or from java args
`-Dspring.config.import=optional:file:./cors.yml`
This method **support** reading from **file**, **from url**, **config server**
[Spring documentation about this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#config-data-import)

For reading CORS configuration from properties file you may use library (I'm developer of this)

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.github.iruzhnikov</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc-cors-properties-autoconfigure</artifactId>
  <version>VERSION</version>
</dependency>
```

and properties config

```yml
spring:
  web:
    cors:
      enabled: true
      mappings: #spring.web.cors.mappings.<any_name>.<property>: <value>
        anyName: #just any name, just for grouping properties under the same path pattern (not used in internal logic)
          paths: #ant style path pattern, ATTENTION! not ordered, /** pattern override all other pattern
            - /path/to/api
            - /path/to/api/**
          #allowed-origins: "*"
          allowed-methods: GET #Enable override all defaults! If disabled: a lot more from all the controller methods included from the path pattern matches
          #allowed-headers: "*"
          #exposed-headers: ('*' - not-supported)
          #allow-credentials: true
          allowed-origin-patterns: .*
          #max-age: PT30M
```